# Servlet libraries are not defined in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to make a simple servlet in Eclipse. But including the following libraries generates errors as if they were not defined in Eclipse.

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
```

How to have them recognised and defined?

Comment: Did you create a web project or a java project?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I import the javax.servlet API in my Eclipse project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project)

Answer (score 0):

Please add servlet-api.jar in classpath of your project.if you are using tomcat server, then it should be present in ${CATALINA_HOME}/lib

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you are doing the right way:

1. If you are using the Classic version of Eclipse, then you must donwload the [Web Tools Platform](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/).
2. If you have an Eclipse Java EE Edition, then there is already installed the necessary plugins.
3. Create a new Dynamic Web Project: Menu **New > Project > Dynamic Web Project**.
4. Fill all values you want for the new project.
5. Do right click on the project and select New Servlet.
6. Last step creates a new Class file that is a servlet class, already importing the necessary packages, such as javax.servlet.http.*.

If you are using a Eclipse with a Maven plugin installed then, after configured it, you can only add the following dependencies:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api/2.5

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl/1.2

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jsp-api/2.0

In fact, you can see this tutorial explaining very well all the steps to create a [Dynamic Web Prroject using WTP](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseWTP/).
Or by ugin Maven, [this one](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-web-application-project-with-maven/) and [this full explained](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/03/01/building-web-applications-with-maven-2.html).

Hope this help...